# How to use a Interceptor from NHibernate config XML file?

Tags: nhibernate, interceptor

I want to use a nhibernate interceptor (overriding EmptyInterceptor) without code change.

It's possible to do it from XML config file?

My EmptyInterceptor override class:

```
public class QueryNumberInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor {
        public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql) {
            return base.OnPrepareStatement(sql);
        }
}
```

My XML config file:

```
<config>
    <add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver, NHibernate"/>
    <add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect, NHibernate"/>
    <add key="connection.connection_string" value="ConnectionString = ${MainConnection}"/>
    <add key="show_sql" value="true"/>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't inject an interceptor with the configuration file.

But you could register an [event listener](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events). You can do pretty the same with event listeners as you can with the interceptor. But its a different concept and therefore looks different.

Comment: In which event I can capture the generated queries ?

Comment: @PatrickCoelho There's no event for that. But tell us what you really need to do (log? add SQL hints? transform the query?); maybe there's an alternative approach.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon I want to count generated query and throw a exception if greater than 30. It will help me to evict N+1 queries.

Comment: @Patrick: You could use the NHibernate profiler (http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) for this. It is not for free, but helps you find performance issues without having a lot of data. You could also use batch size everywhere to avoid N+1 systematically.

Comment: @PatrickCoelho that is not a very good way to detect N+1. It would only be a problem **if**, after that query, individual queries were performed for each of the elements. As Stefan said, there are tools that can detect that effortlessly. NHProf is not free, but you can get a monthly subscription for $26, which is less than you are going to spend chasing the problem manually.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon Thanks. I'm using NHProf, but I want to do an involuntary block to my developer team.